# Serialize/DeSerialize XML where XML element can be chosen either from two xml element

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have a situation where my xml can have either say FileWriter or ArgonWriter as a XML Element.

for example:

```
<Writer>
 <FileWriter>
    <DestinationFolder></DestinationFolder>
</FileWriter
</Writer>
```

or

```
<Writer>
 <HttpWriter>
    <Url></Url>
</Writer>
```

we dont have any relation between FileWriter and HttpWriter neither inherited with common interface or class

I could have write a mapping class to serialize/DeS writer setting as below

```
[Serializable]
public class Writer
{
  [XmlElement]
  public FileWriter {get;set;}

[XmlElement]
  public HttpWriter{get;set;}

}
```

but in this case one of the Writer object always be null

is there any way where I can put a generic code for the same where I don't need to mentioned two object as my root will always have only one xml element ??

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ2XML

```
XDocument doc=XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
var output=doc.Descendants()
              .Elements()
              .Where(x=>x.Name.LocalName=="FileWriter"||x.Name.LocalName =="HttpWriter")
              .Select(e=>
                   new
                   {
                     Type=e.Name.LocalName.ToString(),
                     Path=(x.Element("DestinationFolder")!=null)
                          ? x.Element("DestinationFolder").Value
                          : x.Element("Url").Value
                   });
```

---

You can now iterate over output

```
foreach(var writer in output)
{
    writer.Type;
    writer.Path;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply.. 

I am not sure where I will write this logic to deSerialze my Xml..I m using XmlSerializer here and it does direct mapping of object to Xml or Xml to Object using Xml attribute say [XmlElement].. in this case I am looking for the solution where XmlSerializer does mapping itself (you can say its a ristriction for me as well as we have to follow our current internal FWK  :( ).. also the above my example is just a part of xml.. I have a big Xml and all other elements I am able to serialize it properly...